# Attributes in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have an xproj project which is intended for unit tests. When specifying the attribute Fact i get an error saying

> The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
>   You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.    ClassLibrary1..NET
>   Framework
>   4.5.1 C:\code\RateTheMatch\Trunk\src\ClassLibrary1\Class1.cs  7

```
using Xunit;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Sete()
        {

        }             
    }
}
```

project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "ClassLibrary1 Class Library"
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "dependencies": {
    "xunit": "2.2.0-beta1-build3239",
    "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
    "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
    "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
    "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
    "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net451": { }
  }
}
```

It finds xunit and Fact is resolved as it should be. I get no errors in the package restoration process.

Comment: I think you should add reference to project :System.Runtime

Comment: But i thought i already had. It is there as a dependency in the project.json file.

Comment: @David: You are using the wrong framework moniker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Unit test project is considered an **application**, even though the project type is "Class Library (Package)".

For applications you have to use the `dnx451` moniker. `net451` is only for class libraries. Use the `dnx451` moniker, this should solve your issue.

Not sure if xUnit 2.2 still supports or targets, ASP.NET Core RC1, but for RC1 one your `project.json` should look like this (take from [xunit documentation](https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dnx.html)):

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "description": "",
    "authors": [ "" ],
    "tags": [ "" ],
    "projectUrl": "",
    "licenseUrl": "",
    "dependencies": {
        "xunit": "2.1.0",
        "xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-rc1-build204"
    },
    "commands": {
        "test": "xunit.runner.dnx"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": { },
        "dnxcore50": { }
    }
}
```

Remove the `dnxcore50` moniker, if you don't need it. Many libraries don't target .NET core yet.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification of the usage of the monikers - it seems reasonable. However, changing the framework to dnx451 didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: @David: Which framework version are you using? ASP.NET (5) Core RC1?

Comment: Yes it's the release candidate.